# To create Docker file

Tags: docker

I am making a Docker container image, for this, I have to make docker file in that folder with the app's image So How to create your own docker file for an app while making container image?

Comment: As it stantds, your question doesn't make much sense. What are you making an image for? What app image? Who said you need to make a docker file in that folder? What folder? What app??? Docker has extensive documentation on how to create your own images, I suggest you read through it

Comment: actually, I want to deploy my sample web app on my localhost. So I pull the image from git hub along with docker file then create an image in ubuntu cli and run it on the container. But I wanna know I just copy and paste the dockerfile but don't know how to create it by myself??

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to guide you as you understand everything. Download the installation image (all) here https://owncloud.com/download/. Then take the image extensions and search for tools. Okay, do we understand? Kind regatds ...

Comment: If you are creating your own LXD image. Apply to create a core LXC system image with the application from the Repository, Snap. This way you can start to create any LXD ( Kube ) image, e.g. Kubernetes mikrok8s. Etc. Okay? It depends only on which container you choose, you want to apply, use ...

Comment: Just a refill. If you're preparing LXC with Apps. Gimme a lxc list. And the distribution tool is listed on the right. It is a SNAPSHOT. There is no need for a cluster image. I'm working with a snapshot.